# ssh key doesn't work for one server but works for another

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

debug ssh works

> Authentications that can continue: publickey

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/vinatia/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

debug ssh doesn't work

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/vinatia/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Comment: Are you sure you've transferred your public key to this other server? Are the permissions correct on the `.ssh` directory of the server? What do the sshd logs on the server say?

Comment: Check server logs as well, please.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I'd check first:

Try running `$ grep "ssh" /var/log/syslog` on both client and server hosts. Depending on you distro it could also be `/var/log/messages`. Usually the ssh server/client logs the reason why the authentication was rejected there.

Usually, the culprits are:

On the server:

1. `/etc/sshd_config` has a typo on the path to the `AuthorizedKeysFile` file.
2. `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` has an invalid public key. This can easily happen if you copy&pasted the key and accidentally missed any part of the key.
3. Permissions for `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` are either too loose or too strict.

   ```
   chmod 700 .ssh
   chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

On the client host, the one you are ssh'ing from:

1. Check the permissions for your private key on `~/.ssh/private_key_file`:

```
    chmod 700 .ssh
    chmod 600 .ssh/private_key_file
```

Check these and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the following options in your sshd config?

```
PermitRootLogin
AuthorizedKeysFile
```